# Use jQuery validation with DataAnnotations with DevExpress ASP.NET MVC controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, devexpress

We use DataAnnotations for our viewmodels in our ASP.NET MVC 4 application.
In standard MVC these can be used to generate the markup for jQuery validation.

As we are using DevExpress ASP.NET MVC controls (v13.2), I was wondering if those DataAnnotations attributes can also be generated by the DevExpress controls.

I saw an example where the settings object was used to mark a specific property as required, but that was not with the usage of the DataAnnotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Standard / MVC Validation Modes are supported. Check [Docs](https://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument12060) and [Demos](http://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxDataEditorsDemos/Common/UnobtrusiveValidation).